# Distinct Sum with date range

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a following table:

```
Col_1           Col_2     Col_3      Col_4
01/01/2020      Apple     10         500
05/01/2020      Apple     15         750
05/01/2020      Orange    21         900
08/01/2020      Apple     25         1050
09/01/2020      Banana    40         3200
10/01/2020      Banana    15         1200
11/01/2020      Banana    10         1000
```

I want to show distinct records report  for Col_2 and sum Col_3 and Col_4 for all Apple, Orange and Banana From Date 01/01/2020 to 10/01/2020 from my above table. Example of my report will be like this. How can i create this report.

```
Col_2     Col_3      Col_4
Apple     50         2300
Orange    21         900
Banana    55         4400
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i dont done anything.

Answer (score 0):

To filter report based on dates: go to Report -> Select Expert -> Record -> choose Col_1 and click 'OK' -> choose 'is between' and type in 01/01/2020 and 10/01/2020.

To show distinct records for Col_2 with aggregate measures (such as sum, average, etc.) for the other columns, you must group by Col_2. To do that, go to Report -> Group Expert -> choose Col_2.

Once you have your groups, go to Insert -> Summary -> choose Col_3 as the field to summarize, 'Sum' as the calculation, and 'Group #1' as the summary location.
Repeat this for Col_4

To format like shown in your example table, go to Design view and place 'Group #1 Name' and both your calculated summaries on the same line. You can also create a header for each column using text boxes in the section above the groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solve my problems. Another question is about this matter. I want to filter records for this week and this year. Example: I want to show records of data table col_3 and col_4 for this week and col_3 and col_4 for this year.

Comment: That is a bit more complicated. Because you want to display aggregates for two different date ranges, you are going to have to create Formula Fields for each date range and for each column you want to analyze.

Comment: For example, to create a formula field to get sum of col_3 for this week, you would right click 'Formula Fields' in the Field Explorer, click 'New', name it 'Col_3_this_week' and type: if {YourReportName;1.Col_1} >= 01/01/2020 and {YourReportName;1.Col_1 <= '07/01/2020'
then {YourReportName;1.Col_3}
else 0. Save it. Then in Design view, insert a summary like before, using this new field instead of Col_3.